# Most pythonic way for formatting strings

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, formatting

Problem:

I need to create a complex string from different parts (`nbsp = u'\xa0', data['text'], delimeter`).

I know 3 common solutions:

```
res = '*{nbsp}{nbsp}{nbsp}{nbsp}{0}*{1}'.format(data['text'], delimeter, nbsp=nbsp) # seems unicode error-prone way

res = '*' + 4 * nbsp + data['text'] + '*' + delimeter

res = ''.join(['*', 4 * nbsp, data['text'], '*', delimeter])
```

There is another way with old `%` string formatting way but it looks like it becomes a legacy way.

So which one is most `pythonic` or may be preferable for this certain case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first approach can be improved by uniformly using keyword arguments.

```
u'*{nbsps}{text}*{delimiter}'.format(nbsps=4*nbsp,
                                     text=data['text'],
                                     delimiter=delimiter)
```

The format string makes it clear that it contains three more complex blocks, each of which is defined in the same way in the arguments to `unicode.format`.

Answer (score 1):

*"Pythonic"*, as I understand it, means *"can be deciphered in no time after a year of not seeing the code"*. I would throw the following hat in the ring:

```
res = "*%s%s*%s" % (4*nbsp, str(data["text"]), delimiter)
```

even if you consider it legacy, because it is *understandable*. Read it and compare it with decompiling the above suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Third one is not good solution but first two is good enough. But I prefer mixing it and trying this :

```
str("*"+4*"{0}"+"{1}"+"*"+"{2}").format(nbsp, data['text'], delimeter)
```